# How to do push data to datalayer after Ajax callback?

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a view with many elements and use views load more -> view using views load.

Modules:

- [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more).
- [dataLayer](https://www.drupal.org/project/datalayer).

Is it possible send datalayer event after load elements with AJAX?

I am tracking with Tag manager (Google).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Events were only sent first time and then never.
I solved it purging completely cache, and fixing my google tag.